# how do I decompile a code that has some bugs inside using bytecode?

Tags: smart-contract-wallets, bsc, bug, hack, decompilers

i was tried to understand the codes inside a SC on BSC recently and i found some weird codes inside the decompiled section. i know some little solidity programming and tried to use Remix to reverse it or like that.

> but now im stuck on this specific character: `ΓÇ▓`

you can see in the decompiled section at [this link](https://bscscan.com/bytecode-decompiler?a=0xdcb67e81863bf65930d04728c7775dfad567b451).
so i need to tell you about this SC process:
let's grab `X` and `Y` as wallets and `T` for tokens.
`X` bought the `T` and now X can not sell it.
`X` tried everything like slippage/... to sell `T`, but doesn't work.
`X` transferred `T` to `Y` and now `Y` can sell `X` but not all of them!
it has a sell limitation option in the SC code.
so `Y` tried to sell `n` amount of `T` by default slippage and it works (*it will let `Y` to sell only lower than 180,000 of `T`*).
`Y` approved the token and it's approved on specified block of BSC.
when `Y` tried to sell `T`, it required a sum of series of FEEs.

the default fee on BSC for tokens is now

> Gas limit = 21,000

and

> Gas price(GWEI) = 5

but the T fee requesting is sum of a number that multiplied to another number; it means when `Y` tried to sell `n*x` of `T`, it requires `n+21000+Q0+Q1+...+Qn` (`Qn` = *unknown Real numbers (R)*)

so i tried to understand the process using some tricks on codes but i couldn't solve it because of the `ΓÇ▓` .

here you can see what is happening in this SC:

```
# Palkeoramix decompiler. 
#
#  I failed with these: 
#  - transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value)
#  - transfer(address _to, uint256 _value)
#  All the rest is below.
#

const decimals = 18
const MAX = -1

def storage:
  balanceOf is mapping of uint256 at storage 0
  allowance is mapping of uint256 at storage 1
  totalSupply is uint256 at storage 2
  stor3 is array of struct at storage 3
  stor4 is array of struct at storage 4
  unknownc816841bAddress is addr at storage 5
  unknown03fd2a45Address is addr at storage 6
  unknownf887ea40Address is addr at storage 7

def unknown03fd2a45() payable: 
  return unknown03fd2a45Address

def totalSupply() payable: 
  return totalSupply

def balanceOf(address _owner) payable: 
  require calldata.size - 4 >=ΓÇ▓ 32
  require _owner == _owner
  return balanceOf[addr(_owner)]

def unknownc816841b() payable: 
  return unknownc816841bAddress

def allowance(address _owner, address _spender) payable: 
  require calldata.size - 4 >=ΓÇ▓ 64
  require _owner == _owner
  require _spender == _spender
  return allowance[addr(_owner)][addr(_spender)]

def unknownf887ea40() payable: 
  return unknownf887ea40Address

#
#  Regular functions
#

def _fallback() payable: # default function
  revert

def approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) payable: 
  require calldata.size - 4 >=ΓÇ▓ 64
  require _spender == _spender
  require _value == _value
  if not caller:
      revert with 0x8c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 'ERC20: approve from the zero address'
  if not _spender:
      revert with 0x8c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 'ERC20: approve to the zero address'
  allowance[caller][addr(_spender)] = _value
  log Approval(
        address tokenOwner=_value,
        address spender=caller,
        uint256 tokens=_spender)
  return 1

def increaseAllowance(address _spender, uint256 _addedValue) payable: 
  require calldata.size - 4 >=ΓÇ▓ 64
  require _spender == _spender
  require _addedValue == _addedValue
  if allowance[caller][addr(_spender)] > -_addedValue - 1:
      revert with 'NH{q', 17
  if not caller:
      revert with 0x8c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 'ERC20: approve from the zero address'
  if not _spender:
      revert with 0x8c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 'ERC20: approve to the zero address'
  allowance[caller][addr(_spender)] += _addedValue
  log Approval(
        address tokenOwner=(allowance[caller][addr(_spender)] + _addedValue),
        address spender=caller,
        uint256 tokens=_spender)
  return 1

def decreaseAllowance(address _spender, uint256 _subtractedValue) payable: 
  require calldata.size - 4 >=ΓÇ▓ 64
  require _spender == _spender
  require _subtractedValue == _subtractedValue
  if allowance[caller][addr(_spender)] < _subtractedValue:
      revert with 0x8c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 'ERC20: decreased allowance below zero'
  if not caller:
      revert with 0x8c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 'ERC20: approve from the zero address'
  if not _spender:
      revert with 0x8c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 'ERC20: approve to the zero address'
  allowance[caller][addr(_spender)] -= _subtractedValue
  log Approval(
        address tokenOwner=(allowance[caller][addr(_spender)] - _subtractedValue),
        address spender=caller,
        uint256 tokens=_spender)
  return 1

def name() payable: 
  if bool(stor3.length):
      if not bool(stor3.length) - (stor3.length.field_1 < 32):
          revert with 'NH{q', 34
      if bool(stor3.length):
          if not bool(stor3.length) - (stor3.length.field_1 < 32):
              revert with 'NH{q', 34
          if stor3.length.field_1:
              if 31 < stor3.length.field_1:
                  mem[128] = uint256(stor3.field_0)
                  idx = 128
                  s = 0
                  while stor3.length.field_1 + 96 > idx:
                      mem[idx + 32] = stor3[s].field_256
                      idx = idx + 32
                      s = s + 1
                      continue 
                  return Array(len=2 * Mask(256, -1, stor3.length.field_1), data=mem[128 len ceil32(stor3.length.field_1)])
              mem[128] = 256 * stor3.length.field_8
      else:
          if not bool(stor3.length) - (stor3.length.field_1 < 32):
              revert with 'NH{q', 34
          if stor3.length.field_1:
              if 31 < stor3.length.field_1:
                  mem[128] = uint256(stor3.field_0)
                  idx = 128
                  s = 0
                  while stor3.length.field_1 + 96 > idx:
                      mem[idx + 32] = stor3[s].field_256
                      idx = idx + 32
                      s = s + 1
                      continue 
                  return Array(len=2 * Mask(256, -1, stor3.length.field_1), data=mem[128 len ceil32(stor3.length.field_1)])
              mem[128] = 256 * stor3.length.field_8
      mem[ceil32(stor3.length.field_1) + 192 len ceil32(stor3.length.field_1)] = mem[128 len ceil32(stor3.length.field_1)]
      if ceil32(stor3.length.field_1) > stor3.length.field_1:
          mem[ceil32(stor3.length.field_1) + stor3.length.field_1 + 192] = 0
      return Array(len=2 * Mask(256, -1, stor3.length.field_1), data=mem[128 len ceil32(stor3.length.field_1)], mem[(2 * ceil32(stor3.length.field_1)) + 192 len 2 * ceil32(stor3.length.field_1)]), 
  if not bool(stor3.length) - (stor3.length.field_1 < 32):
      revert with 'NH{q', 34
  if bool(stor3.length):
      if not bool(stor3.length) - (stor3.length.field_1 < 32):
          revert with 'NH{q', 34
      if stor3.length.field_1:
          if 31 < stor3.length.field_1:
              mem[128] = uint256(stor3.field_0)
              idx = 128
              s = 0
              while stor3.length.field_1 + 96 > idx:
                  mem[idx + 32] = stor3[s].field_256
                  idx = idx + 32
                  s = s + 1
                  continue 
              return Array(len=stor3.length % 128, data=mem[128 len ceil32(stor3.length.field_1)])
          mem[128] = 256 * stor3.length.field_8
  else:
      if not bool(stor3.length) - (stor3.length.field_1 < 32):
          revert with 'NH{q', 34
      if stor3.length.field_1:
          if 31 < stor3.length.field_1:
              mem[128] = uint256(stor3.field_0)
              idx = 128
              s = 0
              while stor3.length.field_1 + 96 > idx:
                  mem[idx + 32] = stor3[s].field_256
                  idx = idx + 32
                  s = s + 1
                  continue 
              return Array(len=stor3.length % 128, data=mem[128 len ceil32(stor3.length.field_1)])
          mem[128] = 256 * stor3.length.field_8
  mem[ceil32(stor3.length.field_1) + 192 len ceil32(stor3.length.field_1)] = mem[128 len ceil32(stor3.length.field_1)]
  if ceil32(stor3.length.field_1) > stor3.length.field_1:
      mem[ceil32(stor3.length.field_1) + stor3.length.field_1 + 192] = 0
  return Array(len=stor3.length % 128, data=mem[128 len ceil32(stor3.length.field_1)], mem[(2 * ceil32(stor3.length.field_1)) + 192 len 2 * ceil32(stor3.length.field_1)]), 

def symbol() payable: 
  if bool(stor4.length):
      if not bool(stor4.length) - (stor4.length.field_1 < 32):
          revert with 'NH{q', 34
      if bool(stor4.length):
          if not bool(stor4.length) - (stor4.length.field_1 < 32):
              revert with 'NH{q', 34
          if stor4.length.field_1:
              if 31 < stor4.length.field_1:
                  mem[128] = uint256(stor4.field_0)
                  idx = 128
                  s = 0
                  while stor4.length.field_1 + 96 > idx:
                      mem[idx + 32] = stor4[s].field_256
                      idx = idx + 32
                      s = s + 1
                      continue 
                  return Array(len=2 * Mask(256, -1, stor4.length.field_1), data=mem[128 len ceil32(stor4.length.field_1)])
              mem[128] = 256 * stor4.length.field_8
      else:
          if not bool(stor4.length) - (stor4.length.field_1 < 32):
              revert with 'NH{q', 34
          if stor4.length.field_1:
              if 31 < stor4.length.field_1:
                  mem[128] = uint256(stor4.field_0)
                  idx = 128
                  s = 0
                  while stor4.length.field_1 + 96 > idx:
                      mem[idx + 32] = stor4[s].field_256
                      idx = idx + 32
                      s = s + 1
                      continue 
                  return Array(len=2 * Mask(256, -1, stor4.length.field_1), data=mem[128 len ceil32(stor4.length.field_1)])
              mem[128] = 256 * stor4.length.field_8
      mem[ceil32(stor4.length.field_1) + 192 len ceil32(stor4.length.field_1)] = mem[128 len ceil32(stor4.length.field_1)]
      if ceil32(stor4.length.field_1) > stor4.length.field_1:
          mem[ceil32(stor4.length.field_1) + stor4.length.field_1 + 192] = 0
      return Array(len=2 * Mask(256, -1, stor4.length.field_1), data=mem[128 len ceil32(stor4.length.field_1)], mem[(2 * ceil32(stor4.length.field_1)) + 192 len 2 * ceil32(stor4.length.field_1)]), 
  if not bool(stor4.length) - (stor4.length.field_1 < 32):
      revert with 'NH{q', 34
  if bool(stor4.length):
      if not bool(stor4.length) - (stor4.length.field_1 < 32):
          revert with 'NH{q', 34
      if stor4.length.field_1:
          if 31 < stor4.length.field_1:
              mem[128] = uint256(stor4.field_0)
              idx = 128
              s = 0
              while stor4.length.field_1 + 96 > idx:
                  mem[idx + 32] = stor4[s].field_256
                  idx = idx + 32
                  s = s + 1
                  continue 
              return Array(len=stor4.length % 128, data=mem[128 len ceil32(stor4.length.field_1)])
          mem[128] = 256 * stor4.length.field_8
  else:
      if not bool(stor4.length) - (stor4.length.field_1 < 32):
          revert with 'NH{q', 34
      if stor4.length.field_1:
          if 31 < stor4.length.field_1:
              mem[128] = uint256(stor4.field_0)
              idx = 128
              s = 0
              while stor4.length.field_1 + 96 > idx:
                  mem[idx + 32] = stor4[s].field_256
                  idx = idx + 32
                  s = s + 1
                  continue 
              return Array(len=stor4.length % 128, data=mem[128 len ceil32(stor4.length.field_1)])
          mem[128] = 256 * stor4.length.field_8
  mem[ceil32(stor4.length.field_1) + 192 len ceil32(stor4.length.field_1)] = mem[128 len ceil32(stor4.length.field_1)]
  if ceil32(stor4.length.field_1) > stor4.length.field_1:
      mem[ceil32(stor4.length.field_1) + stor4.length.field_1 + 192] = 0
  return Array(len=stor4.length % 128, data=mem[128 len ceil32(stor4.length.field_1)], mem[(2 * ceil32(stor4.length.field_1)) + 192 len 2 * ceil32(stor4.length.field_1)]),
```

and the decompiler issues are:

```
 #  - transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value)
 #  - transfer(address _to, uint256 _value)
```

after tried to do some tricks on PCS and sell it, i faced with these issues:

```
Swap failed: Unknown error: "[ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{"value":{"code":-32603,"data":{"code":-32000,"message":"intrinsic gas too low"}}}'". Try increasing your slippage tolerance.
```

so as you can see the `[ethjs-query]` is the minor issue here that cause of the bugs around here as FEE error when `Y` trying to sell it on regular

> Gas Limit

!

i will be appreciate your replies and guidelines for this kind of issue that we will soft-fork the [Eveem's decompiler](https://github.com/eveem-org/panoramix).

Comment: That weird symbol is `′` (running panoramix locally shows it)

Comment: so it will be: require calldata.size - 4 >=′ 64 ? this is none sense!

Comment: I don't know its meaning. In any case you can ignore it I think

Comment: NO way, it is the most part of this scam code. just look at it.

Comment: There's no need to decompile the source code is verified for that contract, https://bscscan.com/address/0xdcb67e81863bf65930d04728c7775dfad567b451#code. The scam part is used in the unverified token https://bscscan.com/address/0x8934390edEE6C7E49435560C9B3150117a968812#code.